# How to show Promotion description on associated product page In Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a promotional shopping cart price rule for category id **87** as shown in below image-

[image]

Now I want to show its description on all those product's view page on frontend which satisfy this rule like in  my case this description should show on all products which are under category with id **87**

On product view page at frontend I want to show promotional description as shown in below image--

[image]

Comment: You might find more help over at [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)